# RPM Require installs wrong dependency

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rhel8

I am trying to require Java 1.8.0 in my .spec file for building a custom RPM.  I am depending on java-1.8.0-openjdk by adding this line to the spec file:

`Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk`

The problem is that when installing my RPM, it pulls in java-1.8.0-openjdk-slowdebug instead of java-1.8.0-openjdk.  If I just issue a "yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk", it pulls in the correct non-debug version.

This is on RHEL8 by the way.

I have tried setting specific versions in the Require line and that did not work.  I also tried setting a max version with no luck.